# Calling a static method on a generic type parameter in Java

Tags: java

I would like to have something like this in Java :

```
import java.util.List;

class Query<T> {
    public List<T> fetch() {
        // Get the table name, T.tableName()
        // Fetch from /api/<table_name>
        // Parse and return data, T.parseJSON(jsonData)
    }
}
```

The intention here is to have a generic query builder, while each class `T` defines its specific `tableName` and `parseJSON` functions. For example,

```
class Article {
    public static String tableName() {
        return "article";
    }

    public static List<Article> parseJSON(String jsonData) {
        // Parse the json, build the articles
    }
}
```

How do I write the `fetch` function in the `Query` class?

Comment: Why do the methods need to be static?

Comment: They don't need to be. However, if they are instance methods, I don't have an `Article` object to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass an instance of type `T` so you have access to the methods of that type.  Notice the comments..

```
public List<T> fetch(T instance) {
    // Get the table name, instance.TableName();

    // Fetch from /api/<table_name>
    // Parse and return data, instance.parseJSON(jsonData)
}
```

Comment: How are you going to create multiple `T` instances, for the List? And how are you going to invoke `instance.parseJSON` on an unbounded generic `T`? Both of these problems are solvable, but by the time you solve them you've essentially written a `Function<String, T>` in a more complicated way.

Comment: i am not saying this is a "good way" i'm just trying to give the OP an answer under the conditions he has created.  A much better way is to provide a `fetch` that uses an instance that describes all the info needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible; the specific instance of the `T` isn't known at compile time, which is when all static methods are resolved.

A common approach is to make `Query<T>` abstract, and provide a method:

```
protected abstract T parse(String data);
```

You can also use composition: have `Query` take a `Function<String,T>` in its constructor, and use it in `fetch()`. But one way or another, you have to have *something* that resolves at runtime, which is impossible with static methods.

If you use the composition approach, you can pass the json-reading function to each method, rather than the constructor:

```
public List<T> fetch(Function<String, T> parser) {
    ...
}
```

Note that if you do that, you may not even need to make `Query` generic; you can just make each method generic, as needed:

```
public class Query {
    public List<T> fetch(Function<String, T> parser) {
        ...
    }
}
```